# Faster way to concatenate files of same name in different directories

Tags: linux, performance, find, concatenation

I'm trying to do exactly as in this post and used the accepted answer. My question is, is there a faster alternative? This has literally run for several hours and is still creating the new empty files.  I have hundreds of files to concatenate. Thanks!

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/435794/create-new-concatenated-files-of-same-name-in-multiple-directories

Here's the code:

```
find . -type f -path "*/*/*/*/$name" 
-exec cat {} + >"New_Dir/$name" 
done < list_to_concat.txt
```

I've read on similar posts that a loop might be quicker, but not able to get that to work properly. I'm testing with echo here:

```
for i in */*/*/*/*.txt; 
do echo find -name $i -exec bash -c cat $i >>
"New_Dir/$i"; done
```

Comment: The down-vote to this questions would be helpful if explained why...

Comment: I have up-voted it for neutralizing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case this is useful to anyone else searching one day, I learned a much faster way to do this using xargs and ls:

```
while read -r name
do
ls */*/*/*/$name.txt | xargs cat > $name.combine
done <List_to_combine.txt
```